# How do I get the gnuplottex/epstopdf package to work with "-output-dir" and "-aux-dir" option?

Tags: pdftex, gnuplot, epstopdf

I can't seem to get the `gnuplottex` package to work with my preferred compile options. This is a (not too) minimal example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}

%     \usepackage{etoolbox}    % proposed fix (not working)
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\graphicspath{{./tmp/}}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./tmp/}

% proposed fix (not working)
%     \let\nodirfigname\figname
%     \def\figname{./tmp/\nodirfigname}
% 
%     \expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\gnuplot\endcsname
%     {\figname}{\nodirfigname}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
        reset
        plot sin(x)
    \end{gnuplot}
    \caption[Gnuplot]{Gnuplot direkt in \LaTeX}
    \label{fig:gnu}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If I compile the above file via:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=./tmp -aux-directory=./tmp bla.tex
```

I get the following error messages:

> [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] ) Opening gnuplot
>   stream bla-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplotCannot open load file
>   'bla-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot' line 0: util.c: No such file or
>   directory
>
> (./tmp/bla-gnuplottex-fig1.texepstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 17496
>   2010-03-18 17:57:31Z karl $) 2.15 !!! Error: Cannot open
>   bla-gnuplottex-fig1.eps: No such file or directory
>
> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File
>   `./tmp/bla-gnuplottex-fig1-eps-converted-to.pd f' not found.

So obviously `epstopdf` doesn't like my `tmp`-dir too much. How do I get the damn thing to convert the `.eps` files to pdf so that `gnuplottex` can include it? Any ideas?

Comment: Added egreg's proposed fix (in comments). Unfortunately it doesn't work. Error message: `[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! I can't write on file './tmp/bla-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot'.
\gnuplotverbatimwrite ...openout \verbatim@out #1 
                                                  \BeforeStream \let \do \@m...
l.20 ...}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]
! Emergency stop.
\gnuplotverbatimwrite ...openout \verbatim@out #1 
\BeforeStream \let \do \@m...
l.20 ...}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]`

Comment: Did you try removing `\graphicspath`?

Comment: Yep, it's in the example code above...

Comment: It works for me. Ensure that the `tmp` directory exists and you have write privileges in it.

Comment: Been there, done that. Not working, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to patch the `\figname` command of **gnuplottex**, but now the `gnuplot` environment must not use `\figname` and it's necessary to patch also this one

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\nodirfigname\figname
\def\figname{./tmp/\nodirfigname}

\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\gnuplot\endcsname
  {\figname}{\nodirfigname}{}{}
```

The curious way to patch `\gnuplot` is necessary because it's a command having an optional argument.

The code must go after loading **gnuplottex** (of course `\usepackage{etoolbox}` can go anywhere before).

---

**Update**

With `xpatch` it's easier

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\let\nodirfigname\figname
\def\figname{./tmp/\nodirfigname}

\xpatchcmd\gnuplot{\figname}{\nodirfigname}{}{}
```

Comment: Nope, sorry that doesn't work for me. When I try your fix I get: `I can't write on file './tmp/bla-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot'.
\gnuplotverbatimwrite ...openout \verbatim@out #1 
                                                  \BeforeStream \let \do \@m...
l.20 ...}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color]` I edited my post with comments showing where I included your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help though, I could use some more.

Comment: This worked for me (Windows7, Miktex, TeXworks with "-aux-directory=tmp"). Thanks!

Comment: @CorneliusSicker You can use `xpatch` and avoid the funny code

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the update. Actually I had problems with the old version using `etoolbox` when I tried to use the `gnuplot` environment within a subfile embedded in a master document with the help of the `subfiles` package. In this case the figures just would not be rendered (with no errors while compiling). The `xpatch` version seems to have solved that issue.